# Invalid module name in augmentation -- error while using map option for RxJs

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have been receiving the error shown in the attached picture in map.d.ts (first image). Due to this I am not getting a full intellisense as shown in the second image.

I really appreciate any help resolving this issue.

[image: error1]
[image: erro2]

Comment: If you want to name your module `Observable` then you need to do: `declare module Observable`. You don't name a module by a path. Also, please edit your question and add the actual code, while the images are nice they might not be available in the future.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I will add code to replace the images. However, this file map.d.ts is actually part of RxJs package, which I downloaded as a node package. I don't have any control on how it has been written. I can certainly change it but when I update the package that would be overwritten for sure. I think it could be Visual Studio support for the typescript as suggested by OJ Kwon. I will try updating my VS as per the suggestion by OJ Kwon and see that fix the issue. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Oh. Well, then it tries to access a module that it can't find

Answer (score 52):

In your file `.d.ts`, just move all the `import` into the `declare module "moduleName" {}`.

Comment: Your solution didn't work for me. I had to use `import('../.../operator/map').MapSignature` in place of the import and type. For example, in interface listed in the question, I would do `map: import('../.../operator/map').MapSignature`.

Answer (score 1):

add below @import before observable declaration and makes sure your rxjs is above "^5.0.0" in package.json.

```
  import {Observable} from '../../Observable';
  declare module '../../Observable' {
      interface Observable<T> {
        //
      }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

By looking screenshot it seems like you are using Visual Studio which does have typescript language service lower than latest public release by default, does not support module augmentation introduced in typescript@1.8.

There is way to replace language service to latest while waiting Visual studio updates it, refer https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8518 / https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/1696 .